How to best handle keys for signing API callbacks
I am writing an API for a payment system. Third parties can register callback URLs that are linked to an account ID so that whenever a transaction involving that account ID is updated, my API calls the registered callback(s).
Now, the recipient of the callback needs to be able to verify that I indeed called his endpoint. For this, I am considering the following options with the respective associated problems:

1. Shared secret: For each URL, we and the third party who registered it share a secret. I simply hash the secret together with the request data, and the third party does the same to verify the hash.
2. One Public-Private key pair: I generate a PK key pair. The public key can be retrieved from an endpoint that is part of the API (there is no need for a CA). All callbacks will be signed using the private key, which can be verified by a third party using the public key.
3. Many Public-Private key pairs: This combines the first two approaches by generating a PK key pair for each callback and using the respective private key to sign the callback.

Here are some of the problems I can think of with the respective approaches:

1. Storage of the secrets: Since there are potentially a lot of callbacks, secure storage using, e.g., the AWS secret manager, becomes less viable. The alternative is storing them in the database, but in contrast to passwords, I cannot simply store a hash since the original must be hashed with the rest of the request.
2. Key rotations: If only one key is used, it can easily be stored on something like AWS secret manager. However, its exposure will be relatively large, so I should implement key rotations. The main issue here is ensuring everyone is notified and retrieves the new key from the endpoint when needed. Are there some standard approaches here?
3. Storage of the private key: This is a very similar issue to 1. The difference is that the 3rd party now doesn't have to deal with storing the secret securely.

Naturally, I would tend to solution 2. but the issue of key rotations is really bugging me. Note that the goal is to create an easy developer experience. I am not too worried about efficiency. I will provide libraries for either hash or signature verification for the clients so that also isn't a concern.
Which one of the above methods is advisable for a project with potentially a lot of 3rd parties, or am I missing something entirely?

Background/Setup
It's probably worth looking to at what others do, for example consider AWS Access Keys, I am not sure if AWS AK's are a shared secret or a public/private pair, however AWS take responsibility for generating new keys and provide you the key material exactly once. If you loose your keys you can revoke the old one and generate a new one.
Additionally a given user can have at most 2 active keys at once, this helps with key rotation since you can make sure you have switched all your systems over before deactivating/deleting the old key.
With respect to storage of per customer/user key material your system can have a symmetric master key that way per customer keys can be encrypted with the master key then stored into the database - whenever the system needs a customer key it can retrieve it from the database and decrypted with the master key.
Your Questions
If you only have a "single" public/private key pair (shared by all customers) you will have to manage the key rotation schedule (customers cannot choose their own rotation schedule). If you go with this approach I would recommend that you publish 2 (public) keys.
Each time you rotate keys, you remove the oldest key and generate a new one (you always use the oldest active keys for signing your outbound requests) that way your customers have the entire rotation cycle to update the keys on their systems. The expectation here is that customer must accept either key as valid - to avoid a race condition when the rotation happens.
You can then publish your rotation schedule: first of the month, every Sunday etc...
The only advantages I see to the other options are:

The client can choose their own key rotation schedule (some clients may want to rotate more frequently), however I don't see a major issue with having frequent key rotations anyway (daily or hourly).
The client doesn't need to (potentially) validate 2 signing keys.

If you choose one of the other options I would suggest you generate all the keying material and simply download it to the client (similar to AWS), but as noted above I don't see the advantage, I would just use 2 pub/private key pairs for all customers and rotate one of them each cycle.
